# Looking for Java Native API Audio compressing

Tags: java, encoding, mp3, javasound

I am trying to develop an applet java for sound recording and compressing wich work on a diferent plate-forms(Linux, windows and Mac) i need something work natively with java. how can i write my own Java wrapper to LAME (an mp3 encoder) ? or is ther any other compressed formats can be supported by java sound librarys. thanks